# awscli s3: upload via stdin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'd like to upload a tarball to s3 without incurring the cost of a temporary file (we're low on disk). With other utilities, I'd pipe the output of the tar command to the uploading command, but it doesn't Just Work with awscli:

```
$ echo ok | aws s3 cp /dev/stdin s3://my-bucket/test
upload failed: /dev/stdin to s3://my-bucket/test [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: I rolled my own tool that reads `STDIN` and does a multipart upload, because I couldn't find a solution I liked.  Have you tried the aws tool with a fifo?

Answer (score 29):

This should do the trick:

```
tar cv aws-test|aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/aws-test.tar.gz
```

Edit: make sure you're using a newer verison of the aws cli. I've verified that it works with 1.7.3 and it does NOT work with 1.2.9

Note if the file exceeds 50GB, you should pass in an estimate of the file size in bytes using `expected-size`, e.g.:

```
tar cv /home/folder | gzip | s3 cp --expected-size=1234567890 - s3://bucket/folder.tar.gz
```

source: [s3 cp reference docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: This is documented at the end of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: The documentation that @JonathanBallet linked to does not mention `stdin`. If you search for `stream` you will find it. At the end. Just like he said. Yes, I'm lazy. That's why I chose DevOps as a career.

Answer (score 7):

This simple script seems to do the job, but I'd *much* rather not invent my own tool for this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
configfile="aws.ini"
file="/test"
bucket="my-bucket"
resource="/${bucket}${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"

# Grab the config values
eval $(cat aws.ini  | grep -P "^\w+=[-'/\w]+$")

# Calculate the signature.
dateValue=$(date -R)
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
signature=$(
    echo -en "${stringToSign}" |
    openssl sha1 -hmac "${aws_secret_access_key}" -binary |
    base64
)

# PUT!
curl \
    -X PUT \
    --data @- \
    -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
    -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${aws_access_key_id}:${signature}" \
    "https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com${file}"
```

Comment: Still, that is some very nice hackery. +1 for getting the job done.  It will only work up to the 5GB limit for non-multi-part uploads.